In GCP, how to connect to CloudSQL from another project?
I have three projects in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) under one organization: Project A, Project B, and Project C (central). Project C is using a GCP Cloud SQL component (MySQL), which is connected via peering with this project.
I want to establish a connection from VMs in Project A and Project B to the Cloud SQL database "in" Project C. What I’ve tried:

VPC Peering: Set up peering between projects individually: A <-> C <-> DB. This did not work due to non-transitivity in VPC peering.
Shared VPC: Enabled a Shared VPC in Project C and shared it with Project B. I created VMs in both projects, with VMs in Project B having a network interface of the VPC in Project C. Despite this setup, I was only able to connect to the DB from a VM in Project C but not from a VM in Project B.

Steps taken for the Shared VPC:

Created Project B (consumer) and Project C (central).

In Project C created a subnet A with the range 10.0.0.0/24.
Allowed ICMP and SSH with default firewall rules for the VPC.

In Project B Created a subnet A with the range 10.0.1.0/24.
Allowed ICMP and SSH with default firewall rules for the VPC.
For both VPCs:

Created Cloud NAT (gateway and router).

Created a MySQL instance in project C. Enabled Private Service Access (VPC peering technically) and allocated the range 10.0.4.0/24 for the peering. The instance got an IP 10.0.4.3.

Made Project C a Shared VPC host and shared the only subnetwork in this project (project C / subnetwork A), with Project B.

In both projects, created VMs and installed mysql client: The VM in Project C has an IP: 10.0.0.2. The VM in Project B has two network interfaces: subnet A from Project B (10.0.1.2) and subnet A from Project C (10.0.0.3).


Shared VPC tests:

I can connect to MySQL from a VM in Project C; I can ping the VM "in" project B from VM in project C (10.0.0.2 -> 10.0.0.3).
I cannot connect to MySQL from a VM in Project B, even though it has a network interface in the subnet of Project C.

What is the most straightforward solution to allow VMs in Project A and Project B to communicate with the Cloud SQL database in Project C, without using SQLProxy or VPN? What might I be doing wrong in my current setup?
Thank you!

Connectivity options are documented here:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-multiple-vpcs
If you don't want to use a VPN or proxy, you may want to use Private Service Connect.
Another option is a public IP, but that I suppose you would prefer to avoid.
